# Page replacement algorithm - LRU

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to teach myself LRU algorithm using this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bvzVLRsNKM). In the below example ([taken from here](http://cs.uttyler.edu/Faculty/Rainwater/COSC3355/Animations/lrupagereplacement.htm)) why is 0 replaced by 3. Shouldn't that be 4 replaced by 3 as 4 is the least used ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LRU stands for "Least *Recently* Used". It's based on taking advantage of "temporal locality" of reference, i.e. the thought that the same stuff will be used in a period of time.

In your case, the past three accesses before the current one were 0 - 4 - 2. This means that of the pages in physical memory, 0 was the least recently used, and so it gets paged out.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused between concept of LRU and Optimal Replacement Algo.
In above stack 0 was used before using 4 so when replacement is to be done then 0 is most recently used as compared to 4 and 2 which too are in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Least Recently Used means if we have 3 frames memory and we have pages 4 9 7 5. So 4, 9 and 7 will be added into frames. Now we want to replace page 5. So we will check in memory which page is Least Recently Used in our case page no 4 is LRU so we will replace  4 with 5.

In your case **2 is Ist Recently Used, 4 is 2nd Recently Used and 0 is Least Recently Used** so we will replace 0 with 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Page replacement algorithm LRU (LEAST RECENTLY USED) Code in C language**

```
#include<stdio.h>



int findLRU(int time[], int n);


int main()
{
    int frame_size, no_of_pages, counter = 0, flag1,f, flag2, i, j, m, pos, page_faults = 0;
    int frames[10], pages[30], time[10], pri[20][20];
    char x[20];
        float fault_ratio,hit_ratio;

        printf("Enter Total number of pages: ");
    scanf("%d", &no_of_pages);



        printf("Enter value of page number: ");
        printf("\n");

        for(i = 0; i < no_of_pages; i++)


  {

            scanf("%d", &pages[i]);
      }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter number of frames: ");
    scanf("%d", &frame_size);

        for(i=0; i< no_of_pages; i++)
        {
                x[i]='X';
        }
    for(i = 0; i < frame_size; ++i)
        {
                frames[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < no_of_pages; ++i)
    {
                flag1 = flag2 = 0;

                for(j = 0; j < frame_size; ++j)
                {
                    if(frames[j] == pages[i])
                    {
                                counter++;
                                time[j] = counter;
                           flag1 = flag2 = 1;
                           page_faults--;
                           x[i]='*';
                           page_faults++;
                           break;

                        }
                }

                if(flag1 == 0)
                {
                    for(j = 0; j < frame_size; ++j)
                        {

                                if(frames[j] == 0)
                                {
                                    counter++;
                                    page_faults++;
                                    frames[j] = pages[i];
                                    time[j] = counter;
                                    flag2 = 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                        }
                }

                if(flag2 == 0)
                {
                    pos = findLRU(time, frame_size);
                    counter++;
                    page_faults++;

                    frames[pos] = pages[i];
                    time[pos] = counter;
                }

                for(j = 0; j < frame_size; j++)
                {
                    pri[j][i]=frames[j];
                }
    }

        printf("\n");
                for(i = 0 ; i <no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size+1; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }

                printf("\n|       |");
                for(i=1;i<=(no_of_pages*4)/2;i++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
                printf("Pages");
                for(i=(no_of_pages*4)/2;i<=(no_of_pages*4)+13;i++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

                printf("|\n");
        printf("|Frames |");

                        for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size - 8; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }
                printf("\n|\t|");



                for(i=0 ; i < no_of_pages ; i++)
                {
                        printf(" %2d |",pages[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
                for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size+1 ; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }
                printf("\n");

        for(i=0;i<frame_size;i++)
        {

                printf("| %3d",i);
                printf("\t|");

                        for(f=0;f<no_of_pages;f++)
                        {

                                  if(pri[i][f]==0)
                     {
                        printf("  - |");
                      }
                       else
                       {
                        printf(" %2d |",pri[i][f]);
                        }
                }

                        printf("\n");
                }

                for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size+1; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }

        printf("\n|       |");
        for(i = 0; i< no_of_pages; i++)
        {
                if(x[i]=='X')
                {
                        printf("\033[0;31m");
                        printf(" %2c ",x[i]);
                        printf("\033[0m");
                        printf("|");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("\033[0;32m");
                        printf(" %2c ",x[i]);
                        printf("\033[0m");
                        printf("|");
                }
        }

                printf("\n");
                for(i = 0 ; i < no_of_pages*5+2*frame_size+1; i ++)
                {
                        printf("-");
                }

        printf("\n\n Total Page Faults =  Total No of pages - Total Pages hits  \n");
    printf("                   =        %d      -       %d      \n",no_of_pages,(no_of_pages-page_faults));
    printf("                   =        %d      \n",page_faults);

        printf("\n Total Page Hits = Total No of pages - Total Pages Miss \n ");
        printf("                =       %d      -       %d      \n",no_of_pages,page_faults);
        printf("                 =      %d      \n",(no_of_pages-page_faults));

    printf("\nTotal Page Fault ratio = Total Page faults / Total pages \n");
        printf("                       =        %d      /       %d      \n",page_faults,no_of_pages);
        printf("                       =        %5.2f   \n",((float)page_faults/no_of_pages));

    printf("\nTotal Page Hit ratio = Total Page hits / Total pages \n");
    printf("                     =      %d      /       %d      \n",(no_of_pages-page_faults),no_of_pages);
    printf("                     =      %5.2f   \n",((float)no_of_pages-page_faults)/no_of_pages);


    return 0;
}
int findLRU(int time[], int n)
{
    int i, minimum = time[0], pos = 0;


    for(i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        {
                if(time[i] < minimum)
                {
                minimum = time[i];
                pos = i;

                }
    }

    return pos;
}
```